# Should I backup everything in /var/lib/docker?

Tags: docker, backup

I'm currently running Docker 1.12.6 on Ubuntu 17.04, and I would like to know if all directories under */var/lib/docker* should be included in my monthly backup (I backup everything under */* with `rsnapshot`, and then set some `exclude` rules).

With Vagrant, for example, I exclude from the backup downloaded images and their resulting machines (*.vagrant.d/boxes/* and *.VirtualBox/Machines/*), since they can be rebuilt anytime with their respective *Vagrantfile*.

I don't really understand how the `/var/lib/docker` directory structure works, though. It is like the following in my system:

```
# tree -L 2 -a -F --dirsfirst --noreport /var/lib/docker/
/var/lib/docker/
├── aufs/
│   ├── diff/
│   ├── layers/
│   └── mnt/
├── containers/
├── image/
│   └── aufs/
├── network/
│   └── files/
├── swarm/
├── tmp/
├── trust/
└── volumes/
    └── metadata.db
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, all directories under /var/lib/docker should be included in backup.**

A Docker container consists of network settings, volumes, and images. The location of Docker files depends on your operating system.

Here is an overview for the most used operating systems:

- Ubuntu, Fedora and Debian: /var/lib/docker/
- Windows: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
- MacOS: ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/

*(In macOS and Windows, Docker runs Linux containers in a virtual environment.)*

> **Note**
>
> When you upgraded the kernel, without installing an updated version of the aufs kernel module; in that case, the daemon will refuse to start with a message that the "previously used storage driver is not supported". If the daemon fails to start, always read the logs before you take action.
>
> To resolve this, make sure you have the aufs kernel module installed, for example, as explained in the installation docs for [Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate why everything should be included in the backup?